# resizableImageWithCapInsets OR stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24 topCapHeight:15

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage, deprecated

I know stretchable...ist the old one (and deprecated)..and resizable..is new - but ONE BIG problem is here...

The new method ist not working correctly - in my Tests on a tableview i had a lot of lag.

I don't know where the problem is but the line with "away" (i know both same):

```
home = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"homebubble"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(24.0f, 15.0f, 24.0f, 15.0f)];
away = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"awaybubble"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(24.0f, 15.0f, 24.0f, 15.0f)];
```

makes problems - trust me you don't need my hole code, i tested every line, and if i commenting the line with away, everything works fine, but if call both, it lag's.

With the old one it funcs perfect:

```
home = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"homebubble"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24 topCapHeight:15];
away = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"awaybubble"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24 topCapHeight:15];
```

how it can be? Anyone has experience with them? Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

now I know the reason.

It is very very important that the "resizable area" have to be a only 1px. On my project I had a bubble with 43x32 px - the resizabel area was -5x2px (-5 cause the uiedgeinsets was 24,15,24,15) - so it have to me always unsigned, aaaand, it have to be 1px. After more tests it was the solution.

thx for answer.

Comment: What sized image u used?

Comment: @ghazi_jaffary it doesn't matter the size, important is the resizable area -  my pic was (24,15,24,15) - (this answer is really old - just to know)

Comment: thanks alot actually our graphics designer had tough time creating image with 1 pixel resizeable area thats why i asked. Thx alot for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

UIMakeEdgeInsetsMake starts with the top value:

```
UIEdgeInsets UIEdgeInsetsMake (
   CGFloat top,
   CGFloat left,
   CGFloat bottom,
   CGFloat right
);
```

This might be the reason why the new method is not working correctly. Try:

```
home = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"homebubble"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(15.0, 24.0, 15.0, 24.0)];
away = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"awaybubble"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(15.0, 24.0, 15.0, 24.0)];
```

I don't know it that's the reason for your lag thoughT.

Comment: I found the problem. look next.